# SQL Insert into with join and where

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, where-clause

I have three tables. For example:

1. newTable:

   ```
   config_id  | name
   12         | null                    
   22         | null
   ```
2. oldTable:

   ```
   oldTable_id | name   | value
   1           | Jack   | 10                  
   2           | Frank  | 22
   ```
3. associativeTable:

   ```
   config_id    | oldTable_id
   12           | 1                    
   22           | 2
   ```

What I want to do now is:
I want to move the `name` column from `oldTable` to `newTable`. I have already altered `newTable` and added an empty `name` column. Now I'm trying to write a correct `INSERT INTO` statement. What I have so far is:

```
INSERT INTO newTable (name)
SELECT name
FROM oldTable ot join associativeTable at on  ot.oldTable_id = at.oldTable_id
WHERE at.config_id = newTable.config_id;
```

I'm a bit lost on it. I was writing `INSERT INTO` statements before but never when I had an associative table. How would a correct statement look for my case?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I think you're looking for an `UPDATE` statement instead of an `INSERT`?  You want to update the existing rows, now insert new ones

Comment: You are right. So I would need something similar to:
UPDATE newTable nt
INNER JOIN associativeTable at on  nt. config_id = at. config_id
SET nt.name = oldTable.name
WHERE oldTable. oldTable_id = at.oldTable_id;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do it would be using a subquery in the `SET` part:

```
UPDATE newtable n
   SET n.name = (SELECT name 
                   FROM oldtable o 
                   JOIN associativetable a 
                     ON o.oldtable_id = a.oldtable_id 
                    AND a.config_id = n.config_id  
                );
```

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bc0ca0255f81e2665c8070e565082bfe)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it based on an explanation from another website. Working sql script looks like this:

```
UPDATE newTable
    INNER JOIN associativeTable ON (associativeTable.config_id = newTable.config_id)
    INNER JOIN oldTable ON (associativeTable.oldTable_id = oldTable.oldTable_id)
    SET newTable.name = oldTable.name;
```

Answer (score -1):

I really appreciate your sense to directly insert the values from another table already prepared. That will indeed be the practical solution where large tables are concerned.
I think I had a simpler approach to that :)
You could simply have done the following:

```
INSERT INTO newTable
SELECT name FROM oldTable;
```

Do tell me if that didn't work.

Comment: Not sure how this could work without specifying which row in newTable matches oldTable. Nevertheless, it returns an error because the columns count does not match both tables.

Comment: Oh, all right Let me review it once again. Btw, the answer you got seems correct as well